# Using A Custom Exception Form

Tags: c#, exception

I'm currently working on a C# WinForm application, and am trying to create a custom Form to use whenever an uncaught exception is thrown. The reason for this custom form, is to be able to log the details of every thrown exception in a log file, as well as provide the user with a sharp looking GUI with better, and easy to understand details of the error that occurred.

As it stands right now, i am registering for exception events:

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ExceptionHandler.OnThreadException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ExceptionHandler.OnUnhandledException);
```

The ExceptionHandler class logs the error in a log file, and then displays my custom WinForm. My question is, is this the only way to display my custom form? An issue i know of right now, is i am unable to determine whether the application can still continue, or if it will close when the form is closed.

Overall, my question is... Is there a better, or easier way to use my custom exception form? Also, is there a way to know IF the application will be able to recover, once the Exception form is closed?

Comment: If you have an unhandled exception in your application which you obviously didn't know could happen would you really like the user to be able to continue using the application?

Comment: No, but if an unhandled exception occurs, having a better GUI and a ErrorLog with the exception details will help me fix the error in a later release, or at least be able to better assist the user with the error details

Comment: So, exceptions are so non-exceptional in your application that you feel it necessary to write a fancy interface to display them?  Why wouldn't you just write exception data to the event viewer and be done with it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not safe to continue running a program if you don't understand the reason for an exception.

This topic is discussed in more detail here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should start by exiting the application for any error you do not anticipate. The form is a nice touch but beware it may not work, since you do not know what the problem is - so wrap that in a try catch. Then as errors come up do some analysis and if it is something you can recover from than catch that specific exception and recover. Typically though if something bubbles all the way up to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException it is probably something that will leave the app in a bad place and you want to close.